# Upload of the Picture is getting cancelled python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently working on a Bot that creates ad's for me on Ebay-Kleinanzeigen, but I am running into an issue. Everytime when I am trying to upload the picture the upload is getting canceled after not even a second and the rest of the code is getting executed.

This is how my code looks like atm:

```py
path = "C:/Users/dsbh0/Desktop/Ordner/Ebay Kleinanzeigen/Bilder/IMG_1733.PNG"
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys(path)
sleep(10)
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Is there any error also  ?

Comment: Not really, but it seems like the site reloads.